# MongoDb aggregation filter by text search index

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here's my document:

```
{
    id: 1, 
    foos: [
        { id: 11, title: "my bar" },
        { id: 12, title: "my baz" },
    ]
}
```

I want to find this document by ID, then project `foos` that match search string only (using `$text` on indexed field `foos.title`). So searching result for `bar` would look like this:

```
{
    id: 1, 
    foos: [
        { id: 11, title: "my bar" },
    ]
}
```

Is it even possible to do using aggregation pipeline?

Comment: $text search will search and result filtered main documents, but it can't give you filtered sub documents / array of objects.

Comment: @turivishal oh that's what i was afraid of. anyway, thanks for your comment! :)